# How to parse .webp files with Webpack from pictute source HTML tags?

Tags: webpack, webp, webpack-file-loader

I'm using this `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|ico|svg|webp)$/,
              use: [{
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: '[name].[ext]',
                  publicPath: '/img/',
                  outputPath: 'img/'
                }
              }]
            },
        ],
        // ...
    },
    // ...
};
```

And I have this `HTML` code:

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="img/logo.webp">
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="img/logo.jpg">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="..." title="...">
</picture>
```

Now the `logo.jpg` file is parsed based on `img` tag, but the `source` tag's `srcset` paramter is ignored.

How can I tell to the `webpack` to parse the source tags too? Is there any trick, option or maybe a plugin or loader what solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a not working solution for `html-loader` to use attribute setting. Checked the html-srcset-loader too, and some other loaders, but nothing worked.

I just tricked out the webpack with a JavaScript file:

```
import webplogo from './img/logo.webp';
```

This isn't do anything with the image, but the webpack will parse and copy the file into the target directory.

Not a good solution, but working.